# Can't identify SMD component

Tags: identification, components, surface-mount

I need to identify this SMD component, which looks like a tantalum SMD capacitor.
But I can't find specs that would match the marking on a component.
I hope that someone can help me.

[image]

Comment: What device it is?

Comment: @Justme - this is an audio filter in the eurorack format. So quite specific.

Comment: I meant which make and model it is to find a service manual with component list. But it does not matter any more. Spehro already gave the answer.

Comment: @Justme, unfortunately, this device won't have a service manual. Yes, Spehro's answer looks correct, so I accepted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 10V/1uF tantalum capacitor, similar to that shown in [this](https://www.vishay.com/docs/40183/tmctx.pdf) datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and datasheet, exactly what I'm looking for!